# UICollectionView: different size items is not calculated on reused items

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with varied item sizes which i declare in

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FeedItem *item = [_imagesLinkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return CGSizeMake(250, 200*item.sizeFactor);
}
```

When the cell is being reused in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` 
the item is being rendered with the reuesed item size and not the one specified in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method? Also, is it possible that one of the subviews within your cell is being sized independently from the cell causing it to only look like the cell is not being resized?

Comment: Any progress on this? sizeForItemAtIndexPath: is not being recomputed when I scroll and cells are being reused.

Comment: I have the same problem when I scroll down the cells get different alignments (like losing the minimal space in between cells)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is called once on layout preparation, before CollectionView is rendered.

So whenever you scroll and a cell is dequeued it is resized to the size provided by `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` at preparation stage. Are you expecting this method to be called whenever a cell with certain indexPath gets visible? So that you can dynamically change cell size? seems this is not how this method can be used, it can be used to determine the size of a cell once at layout preparation stage.

In case you need the sizes to be recomputed for some reason, you can invalidate the layout using `[UICollectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`.

Answer (score 3):

A collection view seems to recompute items less often than a `UITableView`. You have to inform the collection view about most of the changes to the underlying model, e.g. by calling `[collectionView reloadData]` or `[collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]`.

Comment: This answer pointed me into the right direction. Calling `reloadData` before returning the `CGSize` on the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath` made the magic! Thanks!

Comment: How is the propagated to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Override** this function in **custom layout class.** if you are using custom layout.

```
override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
return true
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simple override the scroll view delegate

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```