# Image view added in collection view cell doesn't apply added constraints

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've added an image to `UICollectionViewCell` and added constraints like the following image.

[image: Cell With Constraints]

**Constraints:**

- Width of ImageView = Width of Cell
- Height of ImageView = Height of Cell
- Align ImageView vertically in container (Cell)
- Align ImageView horizontally in container (Cell)

I'm deciding the cell size at run time using the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    // calculating cell size and returning it
}
```

**Issue:**

In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, when I checked the cell size and image view size both have different values.
Cell {w:82.0, h:145.77}, ImageView {w:380.0,h:170}. Image has the same frame size which I set on storyboard. It is not adjusting based on the constraints.
Is there anyway I can ensure that it have the same size of my cell ?

**Current Fix: (?)**

```
cell.imageView.frame = cell.bounds
```

But it doesn't make any sense. Why I need to set the size explicitly, why the constraints not applied?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer by Marius Soutier: [UICollectionView: different size items is not calculated on reused items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318317/uicollectionview-different-size-items-is-not-calculated-on-reused-items)

The comment below his answer is probably the solution you are looking for.

Basically, you have to call `reloadData` before you return your `CGSize` from `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: No that link doesn't help. As I said in my question, I'm getting correct cell size, the issue is happening for the UIImageView (which doesn't apply the added auto layout constraints).